# How to ssh to remote server using a private key?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two servers. Both servers are in CentOS 5.6. I want to SSH from Server 1 to Server 2 using a private key I have (OpenSSH SSH-2 Private Key).

I don't know how to do it over unix. But what I did on windows using Putty was to feed my OpenSSH private key to putty-gen and generate a private key in PPK format.

However, I would be creating a bash script from server 1 that will execute some commands on server 2 via SSH.

How do I SSH to Server 2 using my private key file from Server 1?

Comment: On many Linux and Unix systems, this can be done using `ssh-copy-id user@machine`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You need your SSH public key and you will need your ssh private key. Keys can be generated with `ssh-keygen`.
The private key must be kept on Server 1 and the public key must be stored on Server 2.

This is completly described in the manpage of openssh, so I will quote a lot of it. You should read the section 'Authentication'. Also the openSSH manual should be really helpful: http://www.openssh.org/manual.html

Please be careful with ssh because this affects the security of your server.

From `man ssh`:

```
 ~/.ssh/identity
 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     Contains the private key for authentication.  These files contain
     sensitive data and should be readable by the user but not acces-
     sible by others (read/write/execute).  ssh will simply ignore a
     private key file if it is accessible by others.  It is possible
     to specify a passphrase when generating the key which will be
     used to encrypt the sensitive part of this file using 3DES.

 ~/.ssh/identity.pub
 ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
     Contains the public key for authentication.  These files are not
     sensitive and can (but need not) be readable by anyone.
```

This means you can store your private key in your home directory in .ssh. Another possibility is to tell ssh via the `-i` parameter switch to use a special identity file.
Also from `man ssh`:

```
 -i identity_file
     Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or
     DSA authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
     protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for pro-
     tocol version 2.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-
     host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have
     multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in config-
     uration files).
```

This is for the private key. Now you need to introduce your public key on Server 2. Again a quote from `man ssh`:

```
  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
         Lists the public keys (RSA/DSA) that can be used for logging in
         as this user.  The format of this file is described in the
         sshd(8) manual page.  This file is not highly sensitive, but the
         recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not
         accessible by others.
```

The easiest way to achive that is to copy the file to Server 2 and append it to the authorized_keys file:

```
scp -p your_pub_key.pub user@host:
ssh user@host
host$ cat id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Authorisation via public key must be allowed for the ssh daemon, see `man ssh_config`. Usually this can be done by adding the following statement to the config file:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the effort but I only need this. `ssh -i keyfile` thanks!

Comment: After generating the key, the easiest and recommended way to install it on the server is with `ssh-copy-id`: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/foo.id_rsa remote.example.com`.

Comment: It's interesting how everyone forgets to mention that u need to run `ssh-add` after creating a key on the computer you are connecting from. that is what causes a headache to most people.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: The client can have many private keys and select based on an arbitrary name in their private ~/.ssh/config file where Host= gives the arbitrary name, HostName gives either a name or IP address, Port= the target port, User is destination username, and ItentityFile= points to the private key file. This feature set is often overlooked and is THE solution to many configuration issues, such as having multiple key-pairs that otherwise collide in name-space.

Comment: When I try and connect with SSH using `$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myuser@ssh.myhost.com` I get the error 
`myuser@ssh.myhost.com: Permission denied (publickey).` I have the key created, added locally using `ssh-add`, and added as an authorized key on the remote server.

Comment: Do not use protocol version 1 as I read but use version 2(id_rsa and id_dsa), probably due to security.

Answer (score 47):

I used ssh with -i option to add your key here.

If you want to pass arg1,arg2 with .sh file, just pass it after .sh file and use a use space to separate it.

`ssh -i home/avr/new.pem ar@231.221.54.8 "/var/www/beta/betatolive.sh mmin 30"`

Comment: Don't forget to set the right permissions: `chmod 600 home/avr/new.pem`

Answer (score 26):

The first thing you’ll need to do is make sure you’ve run the keygen command to generate the keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then use this command to push the key to the remote server, modifying it to match your server name.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: let's call `ssh-copy-id user@hostname` instead

Comment: @andrej Note that `ssh-copy-id` is not part of the official OpenSSH distribution, so it may not be available on all Unices (it seems to be a Linux thing though).

Comment: @Kusalananda good point, thanks. However, this issue requirements are for two CentOS 5.6 machines so they have `ssh-copy-id` for sure.

Comment: Currently, RSA is default key format for `ssh-keygen` so `-t rsa` is not needed. Command to invoke is just `ssh-keygen`.

Answer (score 13):

> ssh-copy-id -- use locally available keys to authorise logins on a remote machine

Use `ssh-copy-id` on Server 1, assuming you have the key pair (generated with `ssh-keygen`):

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@server2_hostname
```

Now you should be able to ssh into Server 2 with ssh using the private key

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@server2_hostname
```

Indeed, if you check `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on Server 2, you'll see the public key is appended for you.

Answer (score 9):

Append the public key (`id_[rd]sa.pub`) for your source machine (where you're sshing from) to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the destination server for the username you want to ssh into.  If you've lost the public key, you'll want to create a new one with `ssh-keygen`.  Using the default arguments for that should be ok for most purposes.   If you need more detailed instructions, there are thousands of tutorials you can google.