# Unable to ssh with private key

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm trying to connect to remote ssh with private key.
But it always prompted to password.

The key file id_rsa (this is copy from the server ~//.ssh/id_rsa file):

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
xxx
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The command :
ssh -vvv -i id_rsa root@xxxx

Here is the logs

```
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xxxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxxx [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxxx:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxxx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DmkwRuhDE+dx8IhUpTXWYekQuvummjbjDVWyMasjNw8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxxx
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 47.241.60.247
debug1: Host 'xxxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: id_rsa  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: id_rsa
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:AdRGwu8qJ2OWmEuqmKqwdUwEcAWuC4ab8hvHccC2Ha8
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:AdRGwu8qJ2OWmEuqmKqwdUwEcAWuC4ab8hvHccC2Ha8
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: have you tried disabling GSSAPI authentication on your machine? Looks like it's both broken and not what you want to use.

Comment: Yes.. still same issue

Comment: Do you have access to the server? What is the result of `grep sshd /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @FelixJN yes i do have access. The syslog is not there

Comment: @NoodleX What exactly means "The syslog is not there"? No output? File doesn't exist? If `/var/log/syslog` does not exist, try `/var/log/messages`. Please [edit] your question to provide requested information or clarification.

Comment: Welcome to unix.se! On the remote host (the one you try to connect to, using that private local key): check that you put the corresponding PUBLIC key (local server "~//.ssh/id_rsa.pub" ?) inside the remote_user "~remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys" file, and check that is is only on 1 line (when pasting it coud become several: fix that), and also that neither .ssh nor authorized_keys are to wildly "open".  (on the remote server (and as that remote user) : chmod 700 ~remote_user/.ssh ; chmod 600 ~remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I still getting a password prompt with ssh with public key authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication)

Comment: [See this posting for the setup steps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/how-to-ssh-to-remote-server-using-a-private-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't/won't try to decipher the log messages, and the following is offered on the basis of your issue with the *password* in your question. Two possibilities for this occur to me:

1. If you're getting a password prompt, that ***may be*** because you *opted* to password-protect your key when you generated your keys with `ssh-keygen`. This is not the same as authenticating yourself to the server with a passphrase - the password created during `ssh-keygen` is to prevent someone else from using the key pair you generated.
2. Just to briefly review basic SSH functionality:

- The system from which you initiate the SSH connection is the **client**.
- The system to which the client connects is the **server**.
- The public & private key generation is done on the **client**
- The public key is transferred from the **client** to the **server**
- There are many good tutorials available on this proedure. [This one from DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) seems like a good one to me.