# ssh tunneling: connection closed by foreign host

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, telnet

I'm trying to create a scenario to test a simple ssh tunneling, just for using a simple telnet.

I have two hosts: **ubuntu** and **suse**. Both of them have the other hostname on /etc/hosts file for address translation.

Ubuntu: I verified and I can connect perfectly via telnet on port 23, as well as ssh via port 22 (with all id_rsa.pub and stuff in order to login via ssh without typing password).

On suse I tried:

```
 ssh -f ubuntu@ubuntu -L 9000:ubuntu:23
 telnet localhost 9000
```

then I get:

```
suse@suse:/etc/ssh> telnet localhost 9000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
Connection closed by foreign host.
suse@suse:/etc/ssh>
```

Any ideias of that error?

Comment: Is port forwarding enabled in sshd config on the target?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open

Answer (score 1):

Try the this command:

```
ssh -f ubuntu@ubuntu -L 9000:localhost:23
```

If this works, it may be a host file issue