# Channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I was doing this  [tutorial](http://simonmott.co.uk/vpn-bonding), but when it comes to the part where O should run these commands:

```
local-server#  ssh -NTCf -w 0:0 87.117.217.27
local-server#  ssh -NTCf -w 1:1 87.117.217.44
```

It says:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you using the `root` account as stated in the tutorial: 'from the root account of your local server'?

Comment: @Lambert Yes, i'm using `root` account and commands are sent from a `#`

Comment: You changed the public IP addresses (87.117.217.27, 87.117.217.44) to match your own right?

Comment: Yes of course, i'm using 172.16.2.1 and 172.16.20.1

Comment: Did you find and read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open?

Comment: Yes, i've tried all those things but it gives me the same failure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23045/discussion-between-lambert-and-badr-oyd).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After discussing this in a chat and debugged the issue, it turned out that the required directive `PermitTunnel yes` was not in place and active. After adding the directive to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and reloading sshd by `service sshd reload` this was resolved.

We added `-v` to the ssh command to get some debugging information and from that we found:

```
debug1: forking to background
root@ubuntu:~# debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Server has rejected tunnel device forwarding
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 0: free: tun, nchannels 1
```

The server actively rejected the tunnel request which pointed us to the right directive.

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen if the (correctly configured) server has recently updated their kernel, but not yet rebooted.

Answer (score 4):

Just found out that I had a space after the IP address in "HostName x.x.x.x{space_here}" and had this error too:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

However it could be seen in logs that there was something strange:

```
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -A some-jump -W x.x.x.x\302\240:22
```

as those \302\240 were quite suspicious.