# Access VM with SSH through VM host

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, port

I have my Linux workstation where I run a virtual machine with another Linux.

The point is that my friend would like to try make `ssh` connect directly to my virtual machine, but we are not able to make it work.

```
ssh -R 2223:linda@virtualMachine:221 linda@workStation
```

This is how we tried it (we tried a lot of options, but this is basically the first idea). 
SSH on virtual machine listening on port 221, so that is why we use this port.

The problem is, that with this command, he connects to my workstation instead of `virtualMachine`.

Why is that happening? Isn't this the way to forwarding SSH connections to the `virtualMachine` address?

Comment: If I understand you mean he cnnects to the host insead of the virtual machine ? right ?

Comment: yes, exactly... and we don't understand why

Comment: ssh -J username@host1:port username@host2:port   should work then (if you already maaged yours keys/permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two ssh commands, one for the tunnel, then another one for login (unless you forward/route ports which you are currently not doing):

```
ssh -f -l linda -L 2211:virtualMachine:221 workStation -N
```

Then

```
ssh -l linda -p 2211 localhost
```

and log in to `virtualMachine` here.

EDIT: Also try (suggested by francois P)

```
ssh -J linda@workStation linda@virtualMachine:221
```

EDIT2: If the problem persists this may be due to options on the jump host (workStation), please also see here: [SSH tunneling error: "channel 1: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open).  Specifially, see whether on workStation the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has these lines

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
PermitOpen any
PermitTunnel yes
```

Restart `sshd` after changes to the file:

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: I am trying this one, but i get error like :                              Bad stdio forwarding specification '192.168.122.153:221:22'
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host ... Is alright, that it automatically add port 22 to the end?

Comment: @dvory59 Did you try the first two commands, or the last one?

Comment: the last one.. We can easily use just two ssh connections, like ssh in ssh, first connect to work station, and then connect to virtual machine.. But i don't think that it's the best solution