# Using ssh -t works to connect over a Jump Host but ssh -W does not work

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm trying to connect my computer `LocalClient` to `RemoteHost` via a `JumpHost` that I have no control over. I have complete control of the `client` and `RemoteHost` (admin privileges)

I can connect to the `RemoteHost` from `LocalClient` perfectly via ssh as:

`ssh -tX relayUserName@JumpHost remoteUser@RemoteHostIP`

My ~/.ssh/config file has the config as:

```
Host RemoteHost
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p JumpHost
```

Now, if I try to tunnel through the `RemoteHost`, I get an error as:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
```

Using `ssh -v`, I get a little more information

```
Authenticated to <JumpHost> ([JumpHostIP]:22).
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd RemoteHostIP:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open), I've checked the values of `sshd_config` in `/etc/ssh/` on `RemoteHost` and (manually) set

`AllowTcpForwarding yes`

The problem still persists and I don't know what else to try.

#### Details:

- OS: `RemoteHost` and `LocalClient` : Kubuntu 18.04 LTS
- ssh versions (arrived via ssh -v ) : `RemoteHost` and `LocalClient`: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`
- ssh version: `JumpHost` (arrived via ssh -v debug1):

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
```

---

As a side note, I need to tunnel to the `RemoteHost` to access a Jupyter Lab instance running with `--no-browser --port=8889` and forward it to my `LocalClient`'s port 8888 for accessing my experiments remotely via a browser on `localhost:8888`

Comment: This looks wrong: `ssh -tX relayUserName@JumpHost remoteUser@RemoteHostIP` Did you mean `ssh -tX relayUserName@JumpHost ssh remoteUser@RemoteHostIP`?

Comment: @OleTange no, just using ```ssh -tX relayUserName@JumpHost remoteUser@RemoteHostIP``` works to connect me to the RemoteHost 
```ssh -tX relayUserName@JumpHost ssh remoteUser@RemoteHostIP``` doesn't even point to the right destination. In fact, the ```JumpHost``` thinks I'm connecting to ```relayUserName@ssh```

Answer (score 1):

`ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p JumpHost` establish forwarding on JumpHost between ssh stdio and %h:%p (which is RemoteHost for your case).

This means the `AllowTcpForwarding yes` configuration must be set on **JumpHost**'s `sshd_config`.
Not RemoteHost as only JumpHost is doing the forwarding from stdio to RemoteHost.

If you can't change sshd_config on JumpHost, you should be able to use this instead, in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host RemoteHost
    ProxyCommand ssh JumpHost netcat %h %p
```

This will do the same as ssh -W, but with basic commands, so the ssh server on JumpHost won't deny it even with AllowTcpFowarding no.

It uses netcat program on JumpHost to redirect ProxyCommand's ssh stdio to another host like this:

```
interactive ssh <= stdio => ProxyCommand's ssh <= network => JumpHost's sshd <= stdio => netcat <= network => RemoteHost
```

[image: Diagram of ssh connections]

See also: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/