# ssh config to start session with google cloud compute instance

Tags: ssh, ssh-config, google-cloud

I would like to use my ssh config to use a google cloud compute instance as a jumpbox to connect to another box.  However, I am having problems getting a config that will allow me to even connect to the google cloud compute instance.

The desired functionality is `ssh gcloud` would connect me to the gcloud instance.  `ssh foo` connects me to a node that I can only connect to through the `gcloud` box.

To connect to gcloud I can run:

```
/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@gcloud
```

So I added an entry to my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host gcloud
    ProxyCommand /home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@gcloud
```

I then run `ssh gcloud` and get:

```
# ssh gcloud
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
-bash: line 1: $'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0\r': command not found
```

It seems to establish a connection, but I don't have a prompt to type at, so I press ctrl-c to kill it.

---

### Debugging

I tried

```
/home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@gcloud --dryrun
```

This shows the ssh command that is run, it adds on a lot of flags I don't really care to have, adding the `--plain` flag gives me a stripped down version, with one `-t` flag.

```
# /home/me/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@gcloud
/usr/bin/ssh -t me@<gcloud_ip>
```

Without adding `--dryrun` I can connect with the `--plain` flag, but not when I use it in my ssh config.  Arguments after `--` are passed to ssh.  This led me to try adding `-- -t` which once again connects, this time no warning is provided and no prompt.  I've also tried `-- -tt` which gives the error and no prompt.

By adding `-- -vvv` I can get more verbose logs, here they are:

```
$ ssh gcloud
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d FIPS  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host <gcloud_ip> originally <gcloud_ip>
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <gcloud_ip> is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host <gcloud_ip> originally <gcloud_ip>
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to <gcloud_ip> [<gcloud_ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 0
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <gcloud_ip>:22 as 'metrics'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:SSiahqZ80hKyZnrwU7tXf7yVH4iw0T1VuGa273/rSm8
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.6046273207033681025
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/me/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:164
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from compute.6046273207033681025
debug1: Host 'compute.6046273207033681025' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:164
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_engine RSA SHA256:v+I+Ar49s9xNTLoC6jSGYwsSeYhHtnCw7B2JWDF8UWs explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_engine RSA SHA256:v+I+Ar49s9xNTLoC6jSGYwsSeYhHtnCw7B2JWDF8UWs explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/me/.ssh/google_compute_engine RSA SHA256:v+I+Ar49s9xNTLoC6jSGYwsSeYhHtnCw7B2JWDF8UWs explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:v+I+Ar49s9xNTLoC6jSGYwsSeYhHtnCw7B2JWDF8UWs
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <gcloud_ip> ([<gcloud_ip>]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=ibus
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 59
-bash: line 1: $'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0\r': command not found
debug2: channel 0: written 59 to efd 8
```

---

As for jumping (my longer-term goal), I can connect to the node with:

```
ssh -J me@<gcloud_ip> -p <port> me@<node_ip>
```

but I would like to encapsulate this in my config so I can say `ssh node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out working syntax, I can connect directly to the gcloud compute instance using the name by adding to my ssh config:

```
Host gcloud
    User me
    ProxyCommand gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@gcloud --command="nc 0.0.0.0 22"
```

Now I can say `ssh gcloud`

To use it as a jumpbox I can add to my config

```
Host *.gc
    User me
    IdentityFile myIdentityFile
    ProxyCommand gcloud compute --project "myproject" ssh --zone "myzone" me@gcloud --command="nc $(basename %h .gc) %p"
```

This allows me to run `ssh <instance_ip>.gc` using the `gcloud` compute instance as a jumpbox.

Comment: This worked. I removed `User me` for gcloud connections

Answer (score 2):

To proxy ssh traffic through a bastion/jumpbox, you need `-W %h:%` in your `ProxyCommand` line. I've provided an example `~/.ssh/config` below.

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
AddKeysToAgent yes

# Bastion/jumpbox
Host gcloud
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null

# Target instance
Host compute.* 10.1.2.*
User me
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey.pem
ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p me@gcloud
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Comment: I am able to connect to the Bastion/jumpbox with these instructions, but for the target instance I get `channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed`, maybe it is some setting on my sshd?  I can use `ssh -J me@<gcloud_ip> -p <port> me@<node_ip>` to jump, but I prefer to use the config.  Also I prefer to use the instance name instead of ip (which is why my example uses the gcloud command), in case the ip changes.

Comment: Added a `Host *` block to the config example. Try that first, but you might need to change sshd config (Troubleshooting thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open). I provided hostname and IP in the example for completeness.