# Can't create SSH SOCKS tunnel with a chroot'ed user

Tags: centos, ssh, ssh-tunneling, chroot, socks5-proxy

I'm attempting to set up a SOCKS proxy via ssh with a user in a chroot jail.  After creating the tunnel, connection attempts result in:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

The client side sets up the tunnel with:

```
ssh -i id_rsa user123@10.0.0.1 -D 1080 -N
```

The server's sshd_config file:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Match User user123
   ChrootDirectory /opt/download
   #X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding yes
   PermitOpen any
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

If I comment out the `ChrootDirectory` config for the user the tunnel works.  If I use `-L` port forwarding on the client with `ChrootDirectory` active it also works.

I'm assuming this has something to do with utilities needed for a SOCKS proxy that aren't visible from the chroot environment but I was unable to find documentation relating to that.  The user's chroot directory currently contains only files that are meant to be retrieved via sftp pulls.

What needs to change to make this work?

Server OS is CentOS 7.8 with OpenSSH 7.4

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open) doesn't apply as it relates to the -L option and I already have the recommended settings in sshd_config.